# how to get nibWithNibName of prototype cell?

Tags: ios

I want use `registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:` method in my app

when i was made custom cell with **xib file** is fine. (ex:**SwitchTableViewCell2.xib** )
because file name is xib name.

working well code:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SwitchTableViewCell2" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"xibcell"];
```

---

but did not working when i made prototypecells on tableview in mainStoryboard.

how to get xibname of prototypecell on storyboard?

**anybody can test this link: [github.com/Kernelzero/test_nav](http://github.com/Kernelzero/test_nav)**

---

**add image files here**

[image]

this controller name : 'PushSettingController'

this controller's storyboard id: 'pushSetting'

[image: property of tableViewController]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use prototype cell,Identifier name must same as dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier name

**NOTE:If you use prototype cell, you don't need to register the cell.Because Prototype cell is not a CustomCell**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"switchcell"];
   if(cell == nil)
   {
     cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   cell.textLabel.text = @"";
   return cell;
}
```

But if you use custom cell,follow the below steps

1.in viewDidLoad you must register the custom cell

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SwitchTableViewCell2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"switchcell"];
```

2.OR in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can write the code below like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *customTableIdentifier=@"switchcell";
  SwitchTableViewCell2 *cell=(SwitchTableViewCell2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customTableIdentifier];
  if (cell==nil)
  {
    NSArray *nibs=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SwitchTableViewCell2" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=[nibs objectAtIndex:0];
  } 
  cell.yourSwitchTableViewCell2Label.text = @"";
  cell.yourSwitchTableViewCell2TextField.text = @"";
  cell.yourSwitchTableViewCell2Button.text = @"";
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: type 'CustomCell' occurs error. My Question is this. how to get name instead of CustomCell

Comment: I try that controllerName, storyboard_id but i can't getting satisfied result

Comment: I mentioned everything in my answer very clearly.If you use prototype cell you don't need to register the cell.

Comment: when tableview set initial view, works fine.
but when pushed with navigation controller, cell does not shown

Comment: I gave answer according to what you have asked.

Comment: I got the solution.Tell me your mail id.I will send your solved project.

Comment: please delete prototype cell from your Push Setting Controller.After that create Custom Cell with Xib.

Comment: i was solve this problem though delete prototype cell and create new xib file. but i want to know how to correct operation of app with prototype cell. thanks @user3182143. And my mail is grosh@naver.com

Comment: I sent the mail to your maid id.Please check it.Kindly tick and up vote my answer.

Comment: sorry I'm late to tapping vote button. :) finally I did not solve this problem with prototypecell. but appreciate you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Take the registerNib call out when using the Storyboard.  If you've set the storyboard up correctly, the prototype cells are already registered to the tableView.

Comment: I just upload screenshot. what is nibname?
identifier and class name is not.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to load it from nib. Call:

Objective-C

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"switchcell];
```

Swift

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("switchcell")
```